# MatLab fixed point method to find the root of a function as an input

Tags: matlab, fixed-point-iteration

I've trouble creating a code for finding roots of a function as an input by the fixed point method,

Here I've done it using Newton-Raphson method:

```
clc,close all
syms x;
fprintf('Newton Raphson\n');
Fun = input('\nType a function \n');
x0 = input('\nType initial value \n');
f = sym(Fun);
df = diff(f,x);
while (1)
   a = subs(f, 'x', x0);
   b = subs(df, 'x', x0);
   x1 = x0 - a/b
   er = (abs((x1 - x0)/x1))*100
   if ( er <= 0.05)
      break;
   end
   x0 = x1;
end
```

And here's a code using the fixed point method but on a fixed function not taken as an input:

```
clc,close all
x0 = 0.5
while (1)
   x1 = (exp(-x0) - sin(x0)) / 5
   er = (abs((x1 - x0)/x1))*100
   if ( er <= 0.05)
      break;
   end
x0 = x1;
```

end

But I can't do it using function as an input because the fixed point method sperates the variable x in the left side.
How can I do it?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to ask.  Newton-Raphson is a fixed point method.

Comment: Newton-Raphson method is different than Fixed Point method, I want to use fixed point method to find the root of a function that is taken as input from the user using Fixed Point method. As I did using the Newton-Raphson one.

Comment: Well actually I'll correct myself.  Newton-Raphson is a special case of the fixed point method.

Comment: Yeah, in the Newton-Raphson method we sub in a specific equation which contains the derivative of the function and the function itself then we get the error, but Fixed-Point case (method), we have to get the x on a sperate side, then we get the error. I wanna know how to do that with a taken function as an input from the user.